# Utilizing Async NPM Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

So... I recently came across this node module: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). I just need a little "show and tell" or a Best Practice approach for the situation I have below. Below you can see my function `GetBearerToken` which takes an argument `{bearer_token:token}` without an issue.

My issue is the variable `ss`. I want to use it outside of this function and pass it to another function to do something. Of course when I try and access `ss`, it's undefined. I have tried some of the ways of making this work as indicated in the documentation, but I am apparently missing something. So any help would be great... Thanks

```
GetBearerToken({
      bearer_token: token
    }, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      if (result) {
        var resultset
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          resultset = (simpleObjectify(result[i].meta, result[i].rows))
        }

        var jstring = JSON.stringify(resultset);
        var obj = JSON.parse(jstring);
        var ss = obj[0].uuid;
        console.log(ss)
      })
```

Outside of function `ss` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you Seth for the editing, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

---

You can try using `.waterfall` method

> **waterfall(tasks, [callback])**
>
> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their
>   results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an
>   error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and
>   the main callback is immediately called with the error.

One example for what you are trying to accomplish

```
async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {

        GetBearerToken({
              bearer_token: token
            }, function(error, result) {
              if (error) throw error;
              if (result) { // *note* don't forget to handle the result properly if an error occurs or the result is not what you expected.
                var resultset
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                  resultset = (simpleObjectify(result[i].meta, result[i].rows))
                }

                var jstring = JSON.stringify(resultset);
                var obj = JSON.parse(jstring);
                var ss = obj[0].uuid;
                callback(null, ss); // call the next callback in waterfall with ss value
              }
            )
          },
          function(arg1, callback) {
            // arg1 now equals ss value 
            callback(null,'all completed');
          }
      ],
      function(err, result) {
        // result now equals 'all completed'
      });
```

but since the code above seems already a step towards to wrong direction when it 
comes to debugging. But take a look at example of  [`.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) who it breaks down the callbacks and then calls the `.waterfall` method.

Comment: Thank you GeoPhoenix for your suggestions. I went ahead and cleaned up the code and took into account your suggestions and example. One final question and I will consider this answered. If I wanted to wrap this whole thing into a greater function and then get the output of the async functionality, say output 1 for complete or 0 for error, what would the best approach be?

Comment: "the best approach" is the one that you understand better and its simpler to be implement. Essentially i would create a waterfall within an waterfall if i were only using `async` but this approach would be complicated for most of the users. I would consider using `events` or promises and structure properly my code be as maintainable and simpler as possible.

Comment: Thank you GeoPhoenix. You are correct, I need to wrap my head around the async concepts a little better. With "events" are you talking about Event Emitter in the EventEmitter Class? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes those are the basic classes i'm sure you can find many modules around who make working with events easier, you don't need to reinvent things.

Comment: Thank you again GeoPhoenix,I believe you have help me out tremendously.